Generalised Jensen-Shannon Divergence - Unequal Length Probability Distributions
I'd like to implement a generalized Jensen-Shannon divergence (GJSD) style test comparing 3 different probability distributions.
In this respect, I looked at the Philentropy library in R with the dummy code below. However, it strikes me that the distributions are all of the same length.
I can understand why this might be the case. But is it possible to compare probability distributions of different length using GJSD-style methods?
Any help would be appreciated.

install.packages("philentropy")
library(philentropy)

#define input probability matrix
Prob <- rbind(1:10/sum(1:10), 20:29/sum(20:29), 30:39/sum(30:39))

# compute the Generalized JSD comparing the PS probability matrix
gJSD(Prob)

